# Styling the groupers on grouped lists - Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Just a quick one. I was wondering what the best way was to style the grouper headers in a grouped list. I want to add a logo to the grouped header along with the standard title it displays. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably setting [$list-header-bg-color](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-css_var-S-list-header-bg-color). Otherwise, CSS to: `.x-list-header div {}`

Hope it helps